# ToolStripDropDown loses mouse autoclose

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

Not sure how to explain this, but:

- there is a control `MyPopup`, made out of `ToolStripDropDown`;
- there are many based on `MyPopup` controls (call them popups);
- there are no problems to open popup **from** the `Form`;
- but there **is** is a problem to open popup **from** popup.

Problem is what after child popup is closed, parent popup stays on screen even when its parent `Form` get focus. The only way to close that stuck parent popup is to get focus to it (with the mouse) and hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

To have popup able to show another popup I have to trick `Closing` event:

```
    void Popup_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent from closing when stay
        if (_stay && e.CloseReason != ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.CloseCalled )
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Before of after closing child popup, parent popup has:

- value of `_stay` is `False`;
- the value of `Popup.AutoClose` is `True`;

I tried to "bring" mouse focus back to the parent popup with the following:

- `TopLevel=true` no luck;
- `Focus();` no luck;
- `Focused=true;` no luck;
- `AutoClose=true;` no luck;
- `Captured=true;` no luck;

Also tried setting above value to `False` and then to `True`, still no luck.

And here is some more code, which could be useful or not:

```
public class MyPopup : UserControl
{
    protected bool _stay = false;

    private ToolStripDropDown _popup;
    private ToolStripControlHost _host;

    public MyPopup()
    {
        // create popup
        _popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
        _popup.Margin = _popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        _popup.AutoSize = false;
        _popup.Closing += Popup_Closing;
        // add host
        _host = new ToolStripControlHost(this);
        _host.Margin = _host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        _host.AutoSize = false;
        _popup.Items.Add(_host);
    }

    public void Show(Control parent, int x, int y)
    {
        _popup.Show(parent, x, y);
    }

    public new void Hide()
    {
        _popup.Close();
    }

    private void Popup_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent from closing when stay
        if (_stay && e.CloseReason != ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.CloseCalled )
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    protected void PopupChildClosedDefaultEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // hide popup if mouse is outside of client region when closing child popup
        if (!ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition)))
            Hide();
        else
        {
            // >> here I am trying different things <<
            _popup.AutoClose = false;
            _popup.AutoClose = true;
        }
    }
}

public class PopupParent: MyPopup
{
    private void TestChildren()
    {
        _stay = true;
        PopupChild popup = new PopupChild();
        popup.Show(button1, 0, 0);
        popup.Closed += PopupChildClosedDefaultEvent;
        _stay = false;
    }
}

public class PopupChild: MyPopup
{
}
```

Question: **Is there any way to fix "broken" popup after it has lost its ability to autoclose on mouse event (clicking somewhere outside of the client area)?**

Comment: This is probably caused by a bug introduced in .NET 4.5, also affecting .NET 4.0.  It got fixed again, pushed through Windows Update.  Be sure to allow it to update your machine.

Comment: win7pro64, all updates, still problem.. will stick to solution with reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, morning bring some freshness to brains and I managed to solve that issue with following:

```
            _popup.Close();
            _popup.Show(_parent, _x, _y);
```

So I have to reshow popup to have it functioning as before. It flickers, but works.

Comment: Thanx for issue. I have same problem. But this post is old. Did you find better way to do this? Without flickering?

Comment: Nope, I didn't a better solution. Simply avoid showing popup in popups.